# Sharepoint 2010 Email Configuration

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

just a quick question. I'm working on a project in Sharepoint Server 2010 standard at the moment and we were just wondering how long it would take to:

- set up an mail server on the same server as our Sharepoint 2010 environment
- configure Sharepoint to use it for incoming emails and outgoing email alerts
- create ~10 customized outgoing email alerts each with the appropriate triggers (a document has been uploaded, a date has been set on a calendar, etc.)
- give each user of a particular role an email address they can use
- make it such that each email sent and received from/to each of these addresses is archived on the system sorted by the relevant correspondant.

  - Make a summary page where all emails are sortable according to the correspondant in question.

I know estimating time is a difficult question at the best of times, we just want a very rough estimate, we'll be having two developers pretty new to sharepoint with an ASP background implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy...

1. set up an mail server on the same server as our Sharepoint 2010 environment **[1 Day]**
2. configure Sharepoint to use it for incoming emails and outgoing email alerts **[1 Hours]**
3. create ~10 customized outgoing email alerts each with the appropriate triggers (a document has been uploaded, a date has been set on a calendar, etc.) **[2 Days]**
4. give each user of a particular role an email address they can use **[1 Hours]**
5. make it such that each email sent and received from/to each of these addresses is archived on the system sorted by the relevant correspondant. **[4 Days]**
6. Make a summary page where all emails are sortable according to the correspondant in question.